# How to get last position of element for animation?

Tags: html, css, angular

I would like to create an animation of an element beyond its own area, while the areas have different css transformations.Therefor I'd like to create a animation like this:

```
animations: [
trigger('length', [
  transition(':increment', [
    query(':enter',
      [
        style({ transform: 'OLDPOSITION' }),
        stagger('100ms', animate('1000ms ease-in-out',
          style({ transform: 'translate(0px, 0px, 0px)' })
        ))
      ], { optional: true }),
  ]),
```

But therefor I need the oldposition of the element before it was added to the new parent.
I was thinking about creating a position servicewhich holds track of all elements i want to move.
Is there a better way to generate a animation while moving child elements in multiple parent elements?

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out.

1. You can detect changes before they will be performed on the DOM. (of course!)
2. You can find HTMLElement by e.g. id and get own ElementRef in constructor
3. Therefor you can calculate the offset

```
    import { ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
    
    export interface Position {
      x: number;
      y: number;
      transform?: string,
    }
    
    export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
      @Input() items: Array = undefined;
    
      constructor(private hostElement: ElementRef) { }
    
      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes.items) {
          let newItems = [...changes.items.currentValue];
          if (changes.items.previousValue) {
            let oldItems = changes.items.previousValue;
            newItems = newItems.filter(item => oldItems.indexOf(item) === -1);
          }
          console.log({ offsets: newItems.map(this.getAnimationOffset.bind(this)) });
        }
      }
    
      getAnimationOffset(identifier: string): Position | undefined {
        let element: HTMLInputElement = document.getElementById(identifier);
        if (element) {
          let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
          let hostRect = this.hostElement.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
          return {
            x: hostRect.x - rect.x,
            y: hostRect.y - rect.y,
            transform: element.style.transform
          };
        }
      }
    }
```